# How to setup remote WebView debugging in Android emulator?

Tags: android, webview, android-emulator, remote-debugging, android-4.4-kitkat

I have successfully set up remote WebView debugging with a real 4.4 device according to [this guide](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging). The guide [also says](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews) that it is possible to debug with Android 4.4 emulators. However I am unable to do so.

Has anyone successfully achieved that?

Comment: i'm looking for that too